# Control Pi Audio via bluetooth from phone

Tags: audio, remote, bluetooth, android

Effectively, I'm attempting to replace an iPod for use in my car to play music with the Pi. But, the special thing here is I want to be able to control what's played over bluetooth with my phone (android). Essentially a remote control for an audio program on the Pi.

I do not want to have the music stored on my phone, but rather on the Pi, and just controlled from my phone.

I've looked around and haven't seen anyone asking this question before, which might mean there's a super simple solution I just don't know about, so I wanted to ask here before I seriously delved into programming an application on the Pi and on my phone, as I've not worked with bluetooth before and it would be a large endeavor.

Comment: One solution might be to run vlc (cvlc) configured with [http access](https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Modules/http_intf/) on your pi and use [VLC Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hobbyistsoftware.android.vlcremote_us) on the android phone. In order to make it work the media library needs to be configured correctly on the pi, but otherwise this mght bee an easy to work solition for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I want to bring up [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com/) as such a tool as I found it easy to set up und it's running well on the Pi.

With extensions it allows you to stream from cloud services (if the Pi would be online) such as Spotify as well as local files. It can be controlled by a multitude of clients (local or remote; command line, graphical, web based, android apps). Packages for installation are available for Debian and Arch Linux, but other than that it can be installed from source and is running on python2.7.

While I did not do any bluetooth remote controlling so far the [mopidy-btmanager](https://github.com/liamw9534/mopidy-btmanager) suggests that this could be done too.

PS: Be sure to pay attention to the power down issues of the Pi (i.e. with respect to the SD card) in an *portable* application with sudden brown/black outs. See various Q&A's here.

Comment: Apparently the B+ has much better brownout protection for the SD card, which is fortunate as that's the model I have. Mopidy looks like something that could work.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know a bluetooth solution, but you could install RuneAudio or Volumio on your Pi. These music players have a web-based interface. If you put a WiFi (or perhaps bluetooth, but this is where I have no experience) dongle in the Pi and configure it as an Access Point (e.g. using `hostapd`), then you can connect your phone in the car to this wifi network, pull up the web-based interface and control your music library and the playback queue.

Comment: Hmm. That is certainly an option. I already have a bluetooth dongle, which is why I wanted to go that route, but unless someone comes up with a better way of doing things, I will most probably take your route.

Comment: Perhaps you can set up a Bluetooth PAN and pull up the web interface through that? As said, I have no bluetooth experience but this might get you somewhere as a start

Comment: Take a look at this site: http://notes.pitfall.org/ip-over-bluetooth-to-a-raspberry-pi.html - they use a PAN.